# Existing Git project - Opening with Visual Studio 2015 shows all files as having been changed/modified

Tags: git, bitbucket, visual-studio-2015

This was an existing Visual Studio project that I had on my machine. It was initialized through git bash and the first commit and sync was done via the command line.

Upon opening the Visual Studio project in Visual Studio, all files are shown as having been changed.

I can easily re-commit the "changes" and re-sync, but I'd like to know why this is happening so I can prevent it in the future.

Comment: Can you check the difference between those files and their previous versions? It could be anything from spacing formats (ie: tabs instead of spaces, number of spaces per tab, etc) to line endings to something else. Please provide more information.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have a previous version of the file. Just initialized this as a git repository, committed and synced to the server. Then upon opening the project, it showed all files as having been modified.

Going to look at my default tabs/spacing - that sounds like it may be the problem

Comment: I am in a similar situation. There are no changes shown between files when right-clicking on them and selecting "Compare with Unmodified" from Visual Studio's "Changes" tab in "Team Explorer".

As an observation - this seems to be happening on the files that come in with somebody else's latest commit when I do a "git pull" or - even more surprisingly - when I do a fresh clone (so there's no merge to speak of).